# Strings coming from distinct distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, p-value

I have a binary classification problem. Two distinct classes of strings are available. The strings are of fixed size and made of three different characters only. I have around $10000$ instances of strings coming from class 1 and $7800$ instances from class 2. Is there any statistical test (like two-sample tests etc) for strings that I can apply to check whether they indeed come from two different distributions?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It sounds like you *know* which population each string comes from, so why would you want to check? Are you faced with *new* strings that you want to assign to one of your distributions?

Comment: Please check if the following makes my question clearer. Each string is 10 characters long, eg: ABBCBCBCBBC, now I have split them into overlapping groups of 3 like {ABB,BBC,BCB..} then applied tfidf to get their vectorized representation. Finally, I have used a classifier to classify the two and got 92% accuracy.

Comment: I want to check the classes' individual distribution and how different they are (kl-divergence etc). Is there any way to do that?